# Java - Center a BoxLayout in a JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, boxlayout

I'm working with JPanel and BoxLayout and I want to Center it on the window, I have this code:

```
    JPanel jorder = new JPanel();
    jorder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jorder, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jorder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Order"));
    JLabel jusuari = new JLabel("User name:         edetorres");
    JLabel jproduct = new JLabel("Product:          Tallat");
    JButton jserve = new JButton("Serve");

    jorder.add(jusuari);
    jorder.add(jproduct);
    jorder.add(jserve);
```

And it returns this (only the left panel of the photo):

[image]

Comment: Looks centred to me. However, do you mean in the middle *vertically*?

Comment: Yes, vertically